# Overriding <tr> onclick, toggle modal in single cell

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where each row is clickable using

```
 echo "<tr class=\"trlink\" onclick=\"location.href='".$row['task_id']."'\">\n";
```

No issues there.

I then have three links inside one cell in this row.  The two that point to different pages work fine.  There is one link however that toggles a modal dialog, it will not display with the onclick included in the  tag.  It works fine without.  I use the following as an

```
<a role=\"button\" href=\"#" . $row['task_id'] . "taskModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
```

Whenever the link is clicked, it goes straight to the href assigned to the .
I assume the issue lies in event bubbling.  I did some googling and found a small Javascript script to cancel the bubbling on click of the modal trigger:

```
function cancelIt(evt) {
var e = (typeof evt != 'undefined') ? evt : event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

And

```
<a href=\"...\" onclick=\"cancelIt(event);\" >
```

on the modal trigger

This solves the problem of loading the initial  link when clicked, however the modal does not display either.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you give more details ? or better yet try to reproduce your issue in http://jsfiddle.net/
Then post the link that we can see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KWqmY/3/).  It might be a hack way to do it, but it works.  Note I also moved the modal `<div>` outside of the `<tr>` because when I closed the modal it would follow the original onclick event for the `<tr>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var trlink = true;
</script>
```

Above sets a variable to check when clicking `tr onclick`.

```
<tr onclick=\"if(trlink) {location.href='google.com'} else { trlink = true; }>
```

This checks if the trlink is true before opening link, if not, sets it true.

```
<a onclick="trlink = false" role="button" href="#1printerModal" data-toggle="modal">None</a>
```

Finally this sets the trlink variable to false before performing any actions in this tag.

I couldn't get the event handling stuff correct, this seems to do the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using the `onclick` event if you're instrumenting your pages with jQuery. Instead, use a `click` handler assigned programatically. This ensures you're not accidentally stomping on something.

Without more details (perhaps a jsfiddle), it's difficult to say for sure what your particular problem is, but one thing you can try is to add some kind of selector to the appropriate anchor tag, then use a paradigm similar to:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#anchorTagICareAbout').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      displayModalDialog();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well this is embarassing.  I've rebuilt a very simplified version in jFiddle here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/BnvGG/8/

At least it helps illustrate what I was trying to do.  I have a much larger scale version of this that seems to be not allowing me to open the modal because of event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the "onmousedown" event instead.

```
<a role=\"button\" href=\"#" . $row['task_id'] . "taskModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\" 
onmousedown=\"event.cancelBubble=true;event.returnValue=false;document.location.hash=this.getAttribute('href').replace('#','');return false;\">
```

Here's a little demo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4dnp/6/

Using proper script assigned event handlers is always preferred, but the above will get the job done. The key part of the code:

```
document.location.hash=this.getAttribute('href').replace('#','')
```

Sets the document.location.hash equal to whatever the value of the links HREF is.